# Fetch the Personalized Prediction Data through the API?

Tags: feature-request, api, users

Is it possible to get a [user's personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) in an automated way?

I'm building a graphical visualization of this data, you can check the project here: http://jlhonora.github.io/stackexchange-predictions/ . To visualize it you need to download the data and then upload it. It would be great if the app could be granted access via OAuth or an alternative.

Comment: Reference: [Blog post introducing "Providence prediction data"](http://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/).

Comment: There is no (documented) API for this and given that this data is somewhat static and tertiary, I would say that this should be a low priority until some rather annoying bugs and missing features are addressed. Meanwhile, **you can write a browser extension to automate getting this data.**  I'm guessing that if such an extension made more than a few requests a day that it might call down lightning bolts from angry sysadmins?

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm afraid that's not possible. The data is downloaded through a post to /users/prediction-data/download , and due to the same origin policy I can't obtain it automatically. Moreover, an `fkey` parameter is sent along with the request, could be a CSRF token or an encoded user id. If the former is the case, then the user is obtained through a cookie, which I wouldn't be able to emulate either.